# Edit .bash_profile in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, osx-snow-leopard, .bash-profile

How do I edit the `bash_profile`? I've tried using the command `chflags` but it shows the error

> [Error writing. Bash_profile: Operation not permitted]

I'm using OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Comment: It could be useful to see the output of these commands `id` and `ls -ld . .bash_profile`

Answer (score 12):

In most cases, the file doesn't even exist unless you specifically create it. In order to do this, you don't need `chflags`. In fact, if you're a typical user, you don't need `chflags` at all with your Mac.

Just enter:

```
cd
touch .bash_profile
```

You can then edit it with whatever application you like, for example a terminal-based editor like `vim`, `nano`, or even TextEdit:

```
vim .bash_profile
nano .bash_profile
open -a "TextEdit" .bash_profile
```

After you've edited the file, make sure to source the `.bash_profile` again. Otherwise, bash won't recognize the changes:

```
source .bash_profile
```

---

If for some reason you don't have permissions, make sure your `.bash_profile` looks like this when doing a directory listing with `ls -la` – i.e. mode 644, owned by yourself.

```
charon:~ werner$ ls -l .bash_profile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 werner  staff  1323 Apr  4 18:00 .bash_profile
```

Comment: Great ! You saved my day !

Answer (score 0):

If you are comformatble using vim that should work fine.

1. Open Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)
2. Type vim .bash_profile